# How to collect a tuple into a HashMap?

Tags: rust, hashmap, clone, traits, collect

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn rank(st: &str, we: Vec<i32>, n: usize) -> &str {
    if st.is_empty() {
        return "No participants";
    }
    
    if n > st.split(',').count() {
        return "Not enough participants";
    }
    
    let win_num = st
        .to_lowercase()
        .split(',')
        .map(|name| name.chars().map(|c| c as i32 - 95i32).sum::<i32>())
        .zip(we.iter())
        .map(|tup| tup.0 * (*tup.1))
        .collect::<Vec<i32>>();
    
    let result = st
        .split(',')
        .cloned()
        .zip(win_num.iter())
        .collect::<HashMap<str, i32>>();
}
```

I'm trying to merge a vector with `&str` slices into a `HashMap` but can't figure out why it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a4f12ca89751a15334eca87f763308a7

Comment: You could use `.fold()`